# Why isn't Bash trap working if output is redirected to stdout?

Tags: bash

Given the following test script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# see "killing timeout": https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57692/65781
declare -a timeout_pids
my_timeout(){
    local args tp
    args="$@"
    timeout $args &
    tp=$!
    #echo "pid of timeout: $tp"
    timeout_pids+=($tp)
    wait $tp
}

cleanup(){
    echo "-----------------------------------------"
    echo "Restoring previous routing table settings"
}

pre_cleanup(){
    echo "Executing pre-cleanup..."
    exit
}

trap pre_cleanup INT
trap cleanup EXIT

echo "ctrl+c now to execute cleanup"
#my_timeout 9s sleep 20 2> /dev/null >/dev/null # <- does not work as expected!
my_timeout 9s sleep 20 2> /dev/null # <- works as expected
```

If the line "does not work" is enabled and the script is run and then `Ctrl+C` is pressed; script is ended immediately, without executing the traps.

If "redirect output to stdout" part is removed (the "works as expected" line is enabled) and then `Ctrl+C` is pressed, the traps are executed.

Why is that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1446594/432690) advises `exec &> /dev/tty`, so traps write to `/dev/tty` regardless of previous redirections:

> The traps are run, but the standard output redirect to `/dev/null` is still in place, so the output is not printed. […] add `exec &> /dev/tty` to work around it by re-establishing the connection from standard output/error to the terminal.

Sometimes this may not be the best solution. Consider a general case when you want your script ("fixed" with `exec &> /dev/tty`) to be silent. You invoke

```
./the_script >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

but then the trap is triggered and it writes to `/dev/tty` anyway.

For me a better way is to store the original stdout and stderr in a form of "backup" file descriptors:

```
# at the very beginning of the script
exec 21>&1
exec 22>&2
```

Then, inside the trap function, you either redirect any single command:

```
echo "Some output" >&21
echo "Some error" >&22
```

or restore the original destinations and proceed as usual:

```
# at the beginning of the trap function
exec 1>&21
exec 2>&22
```

This way the redirections applied to the interrupted command won't affect the trap; still the redirections applied to the entire script will.

Comment: Accepted as this is a more general solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The traps *are* run, but the standard output redirect to /dev/null is still in place, so the output is not printed. Try replacing the `trap` contents with `touch "$FUNCNAME"` to verify, or add `exec &> /dev/tty` to work around it by re-establishing the connection from standard output/error to the terminal. As to why, this may be part of a larger feature to keep a lot of the original environment when running traps in order to avoid surprises.

Comment: Adding `exec &> /dev/tty` to the first line of `pre_cleanup` function body fixed the issue. Thanks.